# Colour intensity while Overlaying images in OPEN CV Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, overlay, transparency, alpha-transparency

[Solution of the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZmsR.png)
I am writing this code which overlays two images with black circles (on white background). The problem is when I write this code, the solution overlays these two circles at respective positions but the colours of the circles fade away a little. Please can you help me write a script which adds both circles but the resulting picture shows both circles as they originally are and not faded?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img1 = cv2.imread('16.bmp') 
img2 = cv2.imread('17.bmp')

img = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)

plt.imshow(img,cmap="gray")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I believe that what's going on is that both bmp images have white backgrounds, and when you add them with a 50% weight the black and white blend to grey. Can you try adding it without weight? Loop over the pixels in the image on top and set any that are white to have an alpha value of 0.

Comment: `img = cv2.addWeighted(img1,1,img2,1,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just go with:

img=cv2.min(img1,img2)

Link:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#min